# DNS Resolving even mobile data turned off for App in iOS

Tags: ios, mobile, dns

I am using Mobile data connection for DNS Name resolving and later data communication with resolved IP. When the Mobile Data Turned OFF for App but main mobile data in Mobile is turned ON, DNS Name is resolving for me but Data communication was not happening.

Please suggest why the DNS name was resolved even mobile data feature for App was OFF.

Comment: Probably because your app doesn't perform DNS lookup, the DNS lookup process in iOS does.